# How do i delete all rows based on a single column in one to many relationship in laravel eloquent?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

When deleting a particular movie , i want to delete all showtime related to it. I have 3 tables related to this query.

1. Showtime (which has m-m relation with times table (pivot table showtime_time)
2. Times
3. Movies

What i tried is:

MovieController:

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    $movie = Movie::findOrFail($id);
    if (ShowTime::where('movie_id', '=', $id)->exists()) {
        $showtimes = ShowTime::whereIn('movie_id', '=', $id)->get();
        foreach ($showtimes as $showtime) {
            $showtime->times()->detach();
            $showtime->delete();
            $movie->delete();
        }
        return back();
    } else {
        $movie->delete();
    }
    return redirect()->route('movies.index');

}
```

Which gave me this error.

> Argument 1 passed to
>   Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::cleanBindings() must be of the type
>   array, string given, called in
>   C:\Users\lenovo\cinetime_nepal_backend\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder.php
>   on line 907

Model class

```
<?php

namespace Modules\Movie\Entities;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class Movie extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = ['id']; //fillable
    protected $hidden = ['created_at', 'updated_at'];

    public function showTimes()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(ShowTime::class, 'movie_id');
    }
}
```

This is how i am deleting showtime in showtimecontroller

ShowtimeController

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    $showtime = ShowTime::findOrFail($id);
    $showtime->times()->detach();
    $showtime->delete();
    return back();
}
```

I am new to laravel, i searched and tried many codes answered in this site but could not help myself.
Help Please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using MySQL you can add 'ON DELETE CASCADE' to your foreign key. This will automatically delete any records that reference the parent when the parent is deleted. just put it to your showtime migration

```
$table->foreign('movie_id')->references('id')->on('movies')->onDelete('cascade');
```

Or, if you don't want that approach, then you can overwrite your delete method in your movie model. Put this code in your movie model.

```
public function delete() {
    $this->showTimes()->times()->delete();
    $this->showTimes()->delete();
    parent::delete();
}
```

Then in your controller you just delete your movie and it's all fine.

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    $movie = Movie::findOrFail($id);
    $movie->delete();

    return redirect()->route('movies.index');

}
```

Comment: Qonvex620 I tried your second approach but this gave me error "Illuminate\Database\QueryException
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'cinetime_nepal.movie_time' doesn't exist (SQL: delete `times` from `times` inner join `movie_time` on `times`.`id` = `movie_time`.`time_id` where `movie_time`.`movie_id` = 7) "

Comment: check your times relationship in your movie model, maybe its not correct

Comment: it says that in your time table, you dont  have a movie_time column

Comment: thank you but yeah i dont have that column, i want to remove time data with reference to showtime table (so that i could remove showtime just like i remove it in showtime controller)

Comment: My advise is to use the first solution, where you will set already to migration file to avoid that approach

Comment: i have lots of data in server so, i am afraid to follow first approach, but will definitely try that. but as your updated answer previous error was removed showing new error
1- "BadMethodCallException
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany::times() "
 2-
"Bad Method Call
Did you mean Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany::withTimestamps() ?"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206660/discussion-between-nabraj-khadka-and-qonvex620).